# Pandas delete a column value if there exists a row based on another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|    | Filename     | Result    | IssueType                                         | isBad     |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 0  | E0CCG5S237-0 | Bad       | NaN                                               | Yes       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | E0CCG5S237-0 | Bad       | OCR_Text Misrecognition                           | Yes       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 2  | E0CCG5S237-1 | Good      | NaN                                               | Yes       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 3  | E0CCG5S238-0 | Tolerable | MA_Form field elements (checkbox, line element... | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 4  | E0CCG5S238-0 | Tolerable | NaN                                               | Yes       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 5  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | MA_Superscript,subscript and dropcap identific... | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 6  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | Extra Spaces                                      | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 7  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | MA_Link missing from the DV                       | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 8  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | CS_Font Incosistency                              | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 9  | E0CCG5S242-0 | Bad       | ML-OrphanContent                                  | Yes       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 10 | E0CCG5S242-0 | Bad       | Extra Spaces                                      | Tolerable |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I want to group the rows by `Filename` and `Result`, for which I have made the query:
`subj_score_df = subj_score_df.fillna('').groupby(['Filename', 'Result'])['IssueType'].apply('\n'.join).reset_index()`

But I want to remove `IssueType` value (to `NaN`) if `isBad` column is either `('No', 'Tolerable')` **and there exists at least one other row with same filename** where `isBad` column has value `'Bad'`.

If there are no row where `isBad` column is `'Bad'` **then no changes in** IssueType.

( For example, here #10 row `IssueType` will be `NaN` as #9 has same filename but has `isBad = Yes` )

Output Dataframe after that:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
|    | Filename     | Result    | IssueType                                         | isBad     |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 0  | E0CCG5S237-0 | Bad       | NaN                                               | Yes       |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | E0CCG5S237-0 | Bad       | OCR_Text Misrecognition                           | Yes       |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 2  | E0CCG5S237-1 | Good      | NaN                                               | Yes       |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 3  | E0CCG5S238-0 | Tolerable | NaN                                               | NaN       | #4's isBad is Yes                |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 4  | E0CCG5S238-0 | Tolerable | NaN                                               | Yes       |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 5  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | MA_Superscript,subscript and dropcap identific... | Tolerable | All are tolerable so no   change |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+                                  |
| 6  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | Extra Spaces                                      | Tolerable |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+                                  |
| 7  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | MA_Link missing from the DV                       | Tolerable |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+                                  |
| 8  | E0CCG5S239-0 | Tolerable | CS_Font Incosistency                              | Tolerable |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 9  | E0CCG5S242-0 | Bad       | ML-OrphanContent                                  | Yes       |                                  |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 10 | E0CCG5S242-0 | Bad       | NaN                                               | Tolerable | #9's isBad is Yes                |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I have edited my question and I will edit the output dataframe as well.

Comment: Is also set `NaN`s to `isBad` column ?

Comment: No. That is only for debugging, I am going to drop that column anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need mask for compare first `isBad` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html):

```
mask = df['isBad'].eq('Yes').groupby(df['Filename']).transform('any')
```

Or use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `Filename`s if `isBad` match condition:

```
mask = df['Filename'].isin(df.loc[df['isBad'].eq('Yes'), 'Filename'])
```

Last set missing values in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with chained condition for match only `Tolerable`:

```
df['IssueType'] = df['IssueType'].mask(mask & df['isBad'].eq('Tolerable'))
print (df)
       Filename     Result                    IssueType      isBad
0   E0CCG5S2370        Bad                          NaN        Yes
1   E0CCG5S2370        Bad      OCR_Text Misrecognition        Yes
2   E0CCG5S2371       Good                          NaN        Yes
3   E0CCG5S2380  Tolerable                          NaN  Tolerable
4   E0CCG5S2380  Tolerable                          NaN        Yes
5   E0CCG5S2390  Tolerable    MA_Superscript,subscript.  Tolerable
6   E0CCG5S2390  Tolerable                 Extra Spaces  Tolerable
7   E0CCG5S2390  Tolerable  MA_Link missing from the DV  Tolerable
8   E0CCG5S2390  Tolerable         CS_Font Incosistency  Tolerable
9   E0CCG5S2420        Bad              MLOrphanContent        Yes
10  E0CCG5S2420        Bad                          NaN  Tolerable
```

Comment: Thanks but it marks all rows IssueType as NaN where isBad is Yes. I wanted to change the IssueType to NaN if it has isBad in 'No', 'Tolerable', only when there is at least one row for a FIlename where isBad is Yes.

Comment: I added the picture of the expected Dataframe in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Just a question `.mask(mask & df['isBad'].eq('Tolerable'))` using chaining. Can I add more conditions? Like `.mask(mask & df['isBad'].eq('Tolerable') & df['isBad'].eq('No') )` ?